# Significant total and indirect effect but insignificant direct effect

Tags: spss, mediation

I was trying to use a simple mediation model (the classic triangular model) to test my hypothesis. However, my data exhibited a significant total effect and a total indirect effect, with the direct effect being insignificant.

Could you please tell me how I should interpret this?

Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an effect of X on Y. You have evidence to suggest that at least part of that effect occurs through the mediator because of the significant indirect effect. You don't have evidence to suggest that at least part of that effect occurs through a mechanism other than the mediator because of the nonsignificant direct effect. You cannot claim full mediation, which means the effect of X on Y occurs entirely through the mediator; for that to occur, you would need to demonstrate that there is no direct effect, and this analysis doesn't establish that. This analysis indicates that you don't know if part of the effect of X on Y occurs through a mechanism other than the mediator, but that you do know that part of the effect occurs through the mediator.

All this assumes correct temporal ordering and no confounding of the X-M, X-Y, and M-Y relationships. If you fail to meet these, then the results cannot be interpreted as mediation.